# Polynomial With Complex Zeros

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> There are nonzero integers $a$, $b$, $r$, and $s$ such that the complex number $r+si$ is a zero of the polynomial $P(x) = x^3 - ax^2 + bx - 65$. For each possible combination of $a$ and $b$, let $p_{a,b}$ be the sum of the zeroes of $P(x)$. Find the sum of the $p_{a,b}$'s for all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$.

Obviously, there are $3$ zeros, $r_1 = r + si, r_2 = r - si, r_3 = k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

By Vieta's formulas, it is easy to see:

$a = k + 2r$, $b = 2kr + r^2 + s^2$, $65 = k(r^2 + s^2)$.

$k$ has to be an integer since $a = k + 2r$ has to be an integer.

Since $65 = 5(13)$, $r^2 + s^2 = 5, (r, s) = (2, 1), (1, 2)$. So $k$ is forced to be $13$.

Case 1: $r = 1$:
$a = k + 2r = 13 + 2 = 15$.

Case 2: $r = 2$: $a = k + 2r = 13 + 4 = 17$.

So: $a = \{15, 17\}$

But I cannot get a proper answer.

Comment: What about the cases $r^2+s^2 = 1,\; r^2 + s^2 = 13,\; r^2 + s^2 = 65$?