# Sum of zeros polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> There are nonzero integers $a$, $b$, $r$, and $s$ such that the complex number $r+si$ is a zero of the polynomial $P(x)={x}^{3}-a{x}^{2}+bx-65$. For each possible combination of $a$ and $b$, let ${p}_{a,b}$ be the sum of the zeros of $P(x)$. Find the sum of the ${p}_{a,b}$'s for all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$.

I get everything from Vieta's Formulas,

$k(r^2 + s^2) = 65$

$b = r^2 + s^2 + 2rk$

$a = k + 2r$

Where $k$ is the third zero (real, integer) of $P(x)$.

There are $3$ cases where, $r^2 + s^2 = 1, 5, 13, 65$

Where (taken from AOPS wiki):
Quote:
If $q = 1$, $r^2 + s^2 = 65$ so (r, s) = $(\pm1, \pm 8), (\pm8, \pm 1), (\pm4, \pm 7), (\pm7, \pm 4)$

Similarly, for $q = 5$, $r^2 + s^2 = 13$ so the pairs $(r,s)$ are $(\pm2, \pm 3), (\pm3, \pm 2)$

For $q = 13$, $r^2 + s^2 = 5$ so the pairs $(r,s)$ are $(\pm2, \pm 1), (\pm1, \pm 2)$

Sum of the roots for $P(x)$ is always $=a = k + 2r$.

Case 1: $a = k + 2r$ where $r = (\pm 1, ....)$.

But then how does it be that,
Quote:
The sum of the  ${p}_{a,b} = a$ for $q = 1$ is $q$ times the number of distinct $r$ values (as each value of $r$ generates a pair $(a,b)$).

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293072/polynomial-with-complex-zeros?rq=1

Comment: Why did you repeat your question from yesterday?

Comment: I asked something different